# Scheduling Packet Retransmission

Tags: c++, c, linux, network-programming, scheduling

I'm programming a network protocol over UDP, using C/C++ in Linux. The protocol must provide reliability, so I'm going to simulate something like TCP retransmission over UDP.

This can be done using *pthreads* or *fork*, but I believe that's an overkill and consumes a lot of system resources. A better approach is to exploit a **scheduler**.

I probably can't use Linux internal scheduler, since I'm programming in user space. Are there standard C/C++ libraries to accomplish this? How about 3rd party libraries?

**Edit:** Some people asked why I'm doing this. Why not use the TCP instead?

The answer is, since I'm implementing a tunneling protocol. If someone tunnels TCP over TCP, the efficiency will drop considerably. Here's more info [Why TCP Over TCP Is A Bad Idea](http://sites.inka.de/sites/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html).

Comment: What makes you think that either threads or forks consume a lot of system resources, or that a scheduler is necessarily better, if you haven't used any of them before?

Comment: What do you mean by "reliability" ? Do you mean to say that the packets must arrive? or do you also require that they not only arrive but also arrive in the correct order? each requirement will require a set of underlying logic, which is not easy to implement for all kinds of n/w activity (not even for the general case if there is such a thing), hence the existence of TCP.

Comment: @SilverbackNet: I used pthreads and forks before! And I said they're overkill because they use a lot of extra data structures. For example, consider a webserver which wants to send 1000 packets (to many clients). It's not wise to create 1000 threads/process just to monitor timeouts.

Comment: @Beh Tou Cheh: I don't want to complicate matters. Scheduling does not have to do with either interpretations. However, you can read [Why TCP Over TCP Is A Bad Idea](http://sites.inka.de/sites/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html) to get why I'm trying this.

Comment: Probably insufficient information for meaningful answer; how you handle retransmission is probably application-specific. If you are trying to duplicate TCP, don't; use it instead.

Comment: @MarkR: see the updated answer for more info.

Comment: If you are implementing a tunneling protocol, why use retransmission at all? I suppose there are some reasons (for example, like wifi, which uses its own acknowledgements and retransmission, because it would otherwise lose an unacceptable amount of packets for many uses)

Comment: @MarkR: When tunneling a reliable protocol (such as TCP) over an unreliable protocol (such as UDP), it is mandatory to implement reliability issues, such as ACKs and retransmission. This is mainly because there's not a 1-1 correspondence between the tunneled protocol (TCP) and the tunneling protocol (UDP): The TCP segments might be fragmented.

Comment: Isn't TCP always implemented over IP, and you tunnel IP over something else (for example IP, or ATM); if a packet gets dropped then TCP will detect it and retransmit. A tunnelled packet being dropped (or a fragment) normally means the whole frame being resent by TCP. Is this not good enough? Wifi uses its own ack/retry for TCP performance because it has a lot of packet loss itself.

Comment: @MarkR: I get your point, but for some reason not totally known to me, the reliability mechanisms in the tunneled protocol does not seem to suffice (I deduced this from the link I provided, as well as implementations such as OpenVPN---see http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/security-overview.html).

Comment: TCP over TCP has one major advantage in some networks: You can offload the handling of nagle's algorithm to the NIC. Of course, if you want to implement a different windowing algorithm for your specific network topology, or one that can scale from modem speed to ten-G, you have to disable that and might as well use UDP.

Comment: @SilverbackNet: Thanks. That's some good news!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample of how to accomplish [asynchronous coroutines with Boost](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/soc/coroutine/coroutine/asio.html). Boost manages the overhead of creating a thread to run the coroutine in this case so that you don't need to. If you would like the kernel to manage your interrupts, you can use [alarm & setitimer](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/libc/Setting-an-Alarm.html), but they're very limited in what they can do.

Any solution will include threads, forks, or some variant of them at some level, unless you synchronously manage the transmission in the main thread using something like select().

Comment: No need for 3rd party libs, asio already has inbuilt coroutines check-out http_server version4: http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_4_7/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.http_server_4 Though you should realize that coroutines in this sense are used to make the code easier to understand (in an fsm manner) and to also reduce the cost incured when using bind (binding and invoking)

Answer (score 5):

The "scheduler" you're after is called "select", and it's a user-space call available in linux. Type "man 2 select" to read the help page for how to use it.

If you need a timeout, just call select() with a timeout value. The select call will return  either when new data has arrived, or a timeout has expired. You can then do retransmissions if there was a timeout.

Comment: Side note: `select` is generally good for a small amount of sockets, otherwise I'd suggest using `poll` or `epoll`.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what exactly you are trying to schedule.  You can use libevent for efficient and somewhat portable interface.  This is basically similar to Matthew's suggestion of using select, but using the most efficient interface (which select is not) on FreeBSD, Linux and MacOS X (actually their page now claims Windows support as well but I'm not too familiar with that).
This will give ability to do non-blocking event-driven network calls.  It will not solve the scheduling part.  DOing it in a separate thread is not going to hurt your performance.  I think running a pthread per connection is not the best approach, but having a single scheduling thread and some worker threads dealing with the network events and maybe some non-trivial processing usually works well.